# Autobahn:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

Tags: java

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Autobahn:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: 
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/ASL2.0
    File1: /Autobahn/libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar
    File2: Autobahn/libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
```

I have been added

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

How do I solve this problem？

Answer (score 0):

Replace jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar and jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
 with jackson-all-1.9.0.jar